# How to check box of DEMOQA practice form

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
hobbies_xpath = f'//input[@type="checkbox"][@value="{row["Hobbies"]}"]/parent::div'
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, hobbies_xpath))).click()
```

With this above code , I am not able to click on the Radio Button of this form https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form. Its throwing error

'selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (578, 460). Other element would receive the click: ...'

Any possible solution would help.

I have tried below code as well.

```
input_hobbies= row['Hobbies']

for hobby in input_hobbies:
    hobbies_xpath = f'//input[@type="checkbox"][@value="{hobby}"]'
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,hobbies_xpath).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input is rendered backward (under) `label` element. It's common situation for custom inputs in automation.

To click on checkbox you should click on label - it would trigger input check action.

For example, you can build xpath selector from element with class `custom-checkbox` which contains any child with text that matches your hobby and get it's `label` child.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form"

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
hobbies = ['Sports', 'Reading', 'Music']

for hobby in hobbies:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, f"//*[contains(@class, 'custom-checkbox') and .//*[contains(.,'{hobby}')]]//label"))).click()
```